# Css Image puzzle - Cross browser compliancy

Tags: css

I am making an image puzzle with css and i am having browser problems.
The image looks like this : 
[image]

My css code is like this:

```
     .Image-collector{position:relative;width:204px;height:204px;margin:0px;padding:0px;
      border-radius:0px;border:0;display:inline-block;}  
     .Image-collector img{position:relative;margin:-2px -4px 0px 0px;
      padding:0px; display:inline- block;border-radius:0px;border:0;horizontal-align:none;}  

     .Image-collector1{position:relative;width:204px;height:204px;margin:0px;padding:0px;
      border-radius:0px;border:0;display:inline-block;}  
     .Image-collector1 img{position:relative;margin:-2px -2.5px 0px 0px;
      padding:0px;display:inline-block;border-radius:0px;border:0;horizontal-align:none;}

     .Image-collector2{position:relative;width:204px;height:204px;margin:0px;padding:0px;
      border-radius:0px;border:0;display:inline-block;}  
     .Image-collector2 img{position:relative;margin:-1px -2px 0px 0px;
      padding:0px;display:inline-block;border-radius:0px;border:0;horizontal-align:none;}
```

So how can i make this work out cross browser ?

Comment: Is a live example possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
 .Image-collector{position:relative;width:204px;height:204px;margin:0px;padding:0px;
  border-radius:0px;border:0;display:inline-block;}  
 .Image-collector img{position:relative;margin:1px 2px 0px 0px;
  padding:0px; display:inline- block;border-radius:0px;border:0;
  horizontal-align:none;float:left;}  

 .Image-collector1{position:relative;width:204px;height:204px;margin:0px;padding:0px;
  border-radius:0px;border:0;display:inline-block;}  
 .Image-collector1 img{position:relative;margin:1px 1px 0px 0px;
  padding:0px;display:inline-block;border-radius:0px;border:0;
  horizontal-align:none;float:left;}

 .Image-collector2{position:relative;width:204px;height:204px;margin:0px;padding:0px;
  border-radius:0px;border:0;display:inline-block;}  
 .Image-collector2 img{position:relative;margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding:0px;display:inline-block;border-radius:0px;border:0;
  horizontal-align:none;float:left;}
```

The last picture does not need margin corruption, like i started with. I only added the - "float:left" to the code to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `display:inline-block`, make sure you don't have any white spaces between your elements. Also `inline-block` elements are affected by `vertical-align` on self and `text-align` on parent.

If you don't want to remove white spaces `font-size` is something that will affect the layout.

A workaround for removeing the white spaces and still have a wrap behaviour is to add an `:after` element with a space in it :

```
.Image-collector:after{ content:' '; font-size:0;}
```

Comment: It just came to my mind that i am not using float.. when adding : "float:left" - it doesn't even need margin corruption to solve it..

Comment: Setting font-size to 0 is not going to work in instances where the user has set a minimum font-size in their browser.